# UITableViewCell Reuse: cell displaying incorrectly - not being reused as expected

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I've created a multi-selection list that allows the selection of multiple Ingredients.

In my tableview, cells can either be enabled or disabled based on the list property of an Ingredient. If the Ingredient's list property is set, the cell will be disabled.

However, when a cell is re-used, it's not displaying as I would expect. The images below explain the problem more effectively than I can.

**(The ingredients that should not be enabled are: Cake Icing, Condensed Milk and Cournflour.)**

[image]

1. The first image shows the three Ingredients disabled and annotated as expected.
2. However, in the second image, scrolling down reveals that some Ingredients are shown to be disabled (but you can select them, and they have full interaction).
3. The third image shows the list after scrolling back up to the top. Some Ingredients have been greyed out, and notice how Cornflour is displayed as enabled, even though you can't interact/select it.

The issue is to do with cell reuse. It appears that the cell is not getting "reset" when reused, and so is keeping some of its "old" appearance.

Below is the code from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, as I'm sure this is where the problem is (although I can't see what's wrong).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }    

    // Fetches the corresponding Ingredient from the ingredientArray
    Ingredient *ingredient = [self.ingredientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Lardr"])
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"   Already in your Lardr";
    }
    else if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Shopping List"])
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"   Already on your Shopping List";
    }
    else
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    }

    // Add a checkmark accessory to the cell if the ingredient is on the selectedIngredients array
    if ([self.selectedIngredients containsObject:ingredient])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.textLabel.text = ingredient.name;

    return cell;
}
```

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure this out, and I've read all SO questions that are even remotely related, but to no avail. What's the problem?!

---

My logic is that for each cell, the textLabel, detailTextLabel, userInteractionEnabled and accessoryType properties are set, no matter which execution path through the if statements, so I can't see why, even after reuse, the cell isn't displaying correctly.

---

**EDIT:** In an attempt to figure out the root of the problem, I've tried "resetting" the cell back to it's default by adding the following right above the line which fetches the corresponding Ingredient: but to no avail.

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.textLabel.text = nil;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;
```

However, what is interesting and completely illogical -- when I moved the following line `cell.textLabel.text = ingredient.name` to directly underneath the line that reads `Ingredient *ingredient = [self.ingredientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, absolutely NO styling is applied to any cell, even though userInteraction is set further below (and the relevant cells are disabled as expected).

I'm thinking, does the order in which a cells properties are set matter? I know it shouldn't, but the appearance changes based on the above.

---

**Update: I've solved the issue; see my answer below.**

Comment: Are you using StoryBoards?

Comment: What's turning the text grey?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code you posted. Setting user interaction to NO doesn't make the text turn gray. I think your problem probably lies with whatever method you're using to do that.

Comment: @rdelmar that's what I was thinking too... but userInteractionEnabled on a cell does turn the text grey, I just tried it. And, I can report that the most basic table view app you can imagine has this very same problem.

Comment: @CarlVeazey, really? I tried it too, and it didn't turn it gray.

Comment: @CarlVeazey, which problem? I copied and pasted the OP's code, and everything is working fine (without doing anything to gray out the text)

Comment: @rdelmar the label problem on reuse. Actual responsiveness to taps is always correct. Started with "Empty Project" template in Xcode. [gist here](https://gist.github.com/cveazey/f132c75e06943888a5c5). Seeing it on my iPhone 5 on iOS 6.1.3

Comment: could this be that the styling of a cell should sit in `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` like the setting of a background color?

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with using a table view controller from the storyboard or not? I made mine in the storyboard, and it works fine. Carl, I see yours doesn't use a storyboard. The OP still hasn't answered that first question.

Comment: Possible dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654551/weird-ios-bug-with-uitableviewcell-and-userinteractionenabled, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793491/uitableviewcell-textcolor-will-not-change-with-userinteractionenabled-no, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498706/static-uitableviewcell-changes-during-viewwillappear-not-reflected-in-display, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967984/change-color-of-uitableviewcell-after-reenabled-userinteraction

Comment: I wouldn't rely on setUserInteraction to affect styling - you should set the text colors, etc independently from setUserInteraction just to be safe.

Comment: Hello everyone. Apologies for the delayed response, just woken up! No, I'm not using storyboards. Everything's created programmatically. My concern is that setting userInteractionEnabled does, and should apply a default styling to the cell, but this affect bleeds onto other cells when the cell is reused, even though it shouldn't because the userInteraction is adjusted accordingly for each cell, or so I thought. Of course, I could adjust the cell's fontColor when setting interactionEnabled, but I really don't think I should have to, and am wondering if this is a bug out of my control.

Comment: setting up color explicitly will solve your problem.because table is reusing your cell which are enabled to draw disable cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue. The problem was that I was setting userInteractionEnabled BEFORE setting the cell's text (thanks to a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654551/weird-ios-bug-with-uitableviewcell-and-userinteractionenabled) from Carl Veazey in the comments).

I fixed the issue by setting the cell's text before adjusting the userInteractionEnabled property. However, there was no styling applied to the cell (even though the cell was disabled). I therefore had to manually style the cell by setting the cell's textColor. Below is the adjusted code with comments.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } 

    // Fetches the relevent ingredient from the ingredientArray
    Ingredient *ingredient = [self.ingredientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = ingredient.name; // Moved this line before setting userInteractionEnabled

    if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Lardr"])
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"   Already in your Lardr";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // Update the color accordingly
    }
    else if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Shopping List"])
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"   Already on your Shopping List";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    // Add a checkmark accessory to the cell if the ingredient is on the selectedIngredients array
    if ([self.selectedIngredients containsObject:ingredient])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Obviously, the order in which you set the properties of a cell should be irrelevant, and so I'm sure that this is a bug. Hope this helps for anybody else who runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Set your cell's color explicitly in **willDisplayCell**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 Ingredient *ingredient = [self.ingredientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Lardr"])
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Shopping List"])
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

}
```

Comment: I've just implemented your suggestion. It still hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: I wanted to set background color in my cell and on cellForRowAtIndexPath it wasn't working, but with this it works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maintainthe list of selected cell in the table view , while reusing the cell just check the cell is already in selection list. If YES just do your customization over there. Try like this.

Declaration

```
 TableViewCell *_selectedCell;
```

Customize the line to store the selected cell and maintain the selection list .

```
_selectedCell = (TableViewCell*)[self.ItemTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:0]];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath check current cell is in the

```
if(_selectedCell)
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];// Customize the cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code with a table view controller from the storyboard, everything worked fine. It seems that there is some bug with the table view that you get by default when not using a storyboard:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Fetches the corresponding Ingredient from the ingredientArray
    Ingredient *ingredient = [self.ingredientArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Lardr"])
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"   Already in your Lardr";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else if ([ingredient.list isEqualToString:@"Shopping List"])
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"   Already on your Shopping List";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    if ([self.selectedIngredients containsObject:ingredient])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.textLabel.text = ingredient.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Notice that I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, and eliminate the if clause. This doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but it's the latest way to do it for a table view in a storyboard.

Comment: did you demonstrate the bug?  in other words, did you witness this code working differently when applied to storyboard and non storyboard tables?  it would be very surprising.

Comment: @danh, yes I have demonstrated the bug using almost the same code above -- since it doesn't have a storyboard, I added the usual if (cell == nil) clause. But other than that, the code was identical to what I posted above. I just alloc init'd a table view controller in the app delegate, and I saw the same behavior as what the OP posted.