# Why is the top tableViewCell gray?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am working with a UITableView in a normal UIViewController. For some reason, the text of the top cell in my TableView is always colored gray.

I have been trying to figure out what causes that cell to be gray, but don't know what it is. The data in my tableView is sourced from an array called *fileList* that gets refreshed during both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Why is the top cell always gray with this code?

(And it does happen both with nothing in the fileList and with many things in the fileList)

```
//MARK: - TableView
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if fileList.count == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return fileList.count
    }
}

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if fileList.count == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No documents found"
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        cell.textLabel?.text = (fileList[indexPath.row])
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        return cell
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue running your code , It's running fine for me.

Even setting `cell.selectionstyle = .grey` is not putting grey color to cell or text.

You have to be more clear about question .

1) What is grey? text color or cell color.

2) What is the code that you are hiding or doing else apart?

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return fileList.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let rowData = fileList[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = rowData
        //cell?.isSelected = true
        cell?.selectionStyle = .gray
        cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black    // if let priceString = rowData[2] as? String { cell.priceLabel.text = "Price: $(priceString)" }
        return cell!
    }

    // Number of sections in table

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }// Default is 1 if not implemented


}
```

Comment: The text color of the cell is grey. There is a bunch of other code - it retrieves the list of files in the user's Documents Directory (or from the app's Ubiquitous Container if iCloud Drive is turned on) which is used to populate the tableview. Nothing other than the extension I shared above does anything to the the tableview or its cells.

Comment: @Grant and its only grey for first cell not any other?

Comment: Yes, it's only the first cell

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the same as the problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552116/8545002). Try setting:

```
cell?.textLabel?.isEnabled = true`
```

in the if statement block for `fileList.count == 0` after the line

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```